# Numpy compare with 2 different dimension array

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

```py
a = np.array([[  0, 100,   0], 
       [  0,   0,   0], 
       [  0,  50,   0]])
b = np.array([0, 50, 0])

c = np.array([0, 0, 1])
```

How can I get array c through a and b, except use `for`? If b equals the item in a, then the same index item of c should be 1.

This question bothers me a lot when I compare a pixel in an image. When I use `for` statement, it will be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way. First, `b` is subtracted from each row of `a` and the absolute value at each index is found. Then, the sum of each row is taken, and if the sum is not 0, then that value in `c` becomes 0. If the sum is 0, then that index row in `a` is equal to `b` and the index in `c` becomes 1.

The absolute value step is necessary in case you have a row in `a` like `[b[0] - 4, b[1] + 4, 0]`, because the sum of that row minus `b` would actually be 0 because of the +4 and -4, even though that row and `b` aren't the same. That's why you need the absolute value step.

```
c = np.sum(np.abs(a - b), axis=1)
c = np.where(c != 0, 0, 1)
```

I tested for `a` with shape `(100000, 3)` and `b` with shape `(3,)`. For my method, the time taken is 0.0085 seconds, while a `for` loop takes 0.0408 seconds, so more than a 4x speedup.

Note that for small `a` (less than ~300 rows, always with 3 columns), the `for` loop is faster.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to output True for a row in a if all values in that row are equal to b?

You can do that like this:

```
result = (a == b).all(axis=1)
```

result will be

```
[False False True]
```

Comment: If you want the values to be [0,0,1] instead of booleans, you can change the datatype to uint8 (same data type used by images) by adding ".astype(np.uint8)" to the end of the code (without the quotes).